Create Procedure with date paramerter error in Oracle
I try to create below procedure
`CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE EXPORT_SALES_BP (FROM_DATE DATE)
AS
BEGIN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE EXP_TMP_SALES';   
INSERT INTO EXP_TMP_SALES 
select SID,STORE_CODE,BP_STORE_CODE,SALES_DATE,INVC_POST_DATE,'0'SALE_TIME,RECEIPT_NO,UPC,QTY,GROSS_AMT,POS,'0'STORE_CODE_STOCK_MOV from (
select A.SID,ST.STORE_CODE,st.UDF1_STRING BP_STORE_CODE,to_char(a.INVC_POST_DATE,'YYYY-MM-DD') Sales_date,a.INVC_POST_DATE,
''SALE_TIME ,a.doc_no  Receipt_NO,I.UPC,
sum(decode(b.item_type,2,b.qty*-1,b.qty)) Qty,round(sum(decode(b.item_type,2,b.qty*1,b.qty)*(b.price)),2) Gross_Amt
,'1' POS,''STORE_CODE_STOCK_MOV
from rps.document a inner join rps.document_item b on a.sid=b.doc_sid
inner join rps.subsidiary s on a.sbs_no=s.sbs_no and b.sbs_no=s.sbs_no 
inner join rps.invn_sbs_item i on b.invn_sbs_item_sid=i.sid and s.sid=i.sbs_sid
inner join rps.store st on st.STORE_CODE=a.STORE_CODE
where   a.receipt_type in (0,1) and b.item_type in (1,2) and a.status=4 AND S.SBS_NO=2 and a.store_code not in ('JC04')
and a.INVC_POST_DATE=:FROM_DATE
group by ST.STORE_CODE,A.SID,to_char(a.INVC_POST_DATE,'YYYY-MM-DD'),a.INVC_POST_DATE,I.UPC,a.doc_no,b.price,b.tax_amt,ST.UDF1_STRING
order by st.UDF1_STRING,to_char(a.INVC_POST_DATE,'YYYY-MM-DD'),a.doc_no) WHERE  Qty<>0
ORDER BY BP_STORE_CODE,SALES_DATE,RECEIPT_NO;
INSERT INTO EXPPORT_SALES_LOG 
SELECT SID,STORE_CODE,BP_STORE_CODE,INVC_POST_DATE,RECEIPT_NO,SUM(QTY)QTY,SUM(GROSS_AMT)GROSS_AMOUNT,SYSDATE EXPORT_DATE FROM JAC_EXP_TMP_SALES WHERE SID NOT IN (SELECT SID FROM  JAC_EXPPORT_SALES_LOG)
GROUP BY SID,STORE_CODE,BP_STORE_CODE,INVC_POST_DATE,RECEIPT_NO;
SELECT BP_STORE_CODE,SALES_DATE,''SALE_TIME,RECEIPT_NO,UPC,QTY,GROSS_AMT,POS,''STORE_CODE_STOCK_MOV FROM  JAC_EXP_TMP_SALES ORDER BY  BP_STORE_CODE,SALES_DATE,RECEIPT_NO;
END
EXPORT_SALES_BP;
/`

Creating the procedure giving me an error
[Error] Compilation (19: 22): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'FROM_DATE'

:FROM_DATE should be FROM_DATE

You have two problems:

:FROM_DATE is a bind variable and you cannot use bind variables in procedures. What you need to use is FROM_DATE (without the leading colon), which is the PL/SQL variable that you define in the procedure's signature.
You cannot use a SELECT statement in PL/SQL without either selecting into variables or opening a cursor. This means that if you fix the first error then your code will still fail to compile due to the final SELECT statement in the procedure. Since you appear to want to return the result set then return a cursor.

You also have the problem that your code has no formatting which makes it very difficult to understand.
You probably want:
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE EXPORT_SALES_BP(
  FROM_DATE IN  DATE,
  o_cursor  OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
AS
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE EXP_TMP_SALES';   

  INSERT INTO EXP_TMP_SALES 
    select A.SID,
           ST.STORE_CODE,
           st.UDF1_STRING AS BP_STORE_CODE,
           to_char(a.INVC_POST_DATE,'YYYY-MM-DD') AS Sales_date,
           a.INVC_POST_DATE,
           '0' AS SALE_TIME,
           a.doc_no AS Receipt_NO,
           I.UPC,
           sum(decode(b.item_type,2,b.qty*-1,b.qty)) AS Qty,
           round(sum(decode(b.item_type,2,b.qty*1,b.qty)*(b.price)),2) AS Gross_Amt,
           '1' AS POS,
           '0' AS STORE_CODE_STOCK_MOV
    from   rps.document a
           inner join rps.document_item b
           on a.sid=b.doc_sid
           inner join rps.subsidiary s
           on a.sbs_no=s.sbs_no and b.sbs_no=s.sbs_no 
           inner join rps.invn_sbs_item i
           on b.invn_sbs_item_sid=i.sid and s.sid=i.sbs_sid
           inner join rps.store st
           on st.STORE_CODE=a.STORE_CODE
    where  a.receipt_type in (0,1)
    and    b.item_type in (1,2)
    and    a.status=4
    AND    S.SBS_NO=2
    and    a.store_code not in ('JC04')
    and    a.INVC_POST_DATE = FROM_DATE
    group by
           ST.STORE_CODE,
           A.SID,
           to_char(a.INVC_POST_DATE,'YYYY-MM-DD'),
           a.INVC_POST_DATE,
           I.UPC,
           a.doc_no,
           b.price,
           b.tax_amt,
           ST.UDF1_STRING
    HAVING sum(decode(b.item_type,2,b.qty*-1,b.qty)) <> 0
    order by
           BP_STORE_CODE,
           SALES_DATE,
           RECEIPT_NO;

  INSERT INTO EXPPORT_SALES_LOG 
    SELECT SID,
           STORE_CODE,
           BP_STORE_CODE,
           INVC_POST_DATE,
           RECEIPT_NO,
           SUM(QTY) QTY,
           SUM(GROSS_AMT) AS GROSS_AMOUNT,
           SYSDATE AS EXPORT_DATE
    FROM   JAC_EXP_TMP_SALES
    WHERE SID NOT IN (SELECT SID FROM  JAC_EXPPORT_SALES_LOG)
    GROUP BY
           SID,
           STORE_CODE,
           BP_STORE_CODE,
           INVC_POST_DATE,
           RECEIPT_NO;

  OPEN o_cursor FOR
    SELECT BP_STORE_CODE,
           SALES_DATE,
           NULL AS SALE_TIME,
           RECEIPT_NO,
           UPC,
           QTY,
           GROSS_AMT,
           POS,
           NULL AS STORE_CODE_STOCK_MOV
    FROM   JAC_EXP_TMP_SALES
    ORDER BY
           BP_STORE_CODE,
           SALES_DATE,
           RECEIPT_NO;
END EXPORT_SALES_BP;
/

In SQL*Plus (and other IDEs that support SQL*Plus commands such as SQL Developer and SQLCl) you can run the procedure using:
VARIABLE v_cursor REFCURSOR;
EXECUTE export_sales_bp(DATE '2024-07-08', :v_cursor);
PRINT v_cursor;

In IDEs that do not support SQL*Plus commands you can use:
DECLARE
  v_cursor      SYS_REFCURSOR;
  v_sid         RPS.DOCUMENT.SID%TYPE;
  v_store_code  RPS.STORE.STORE_CODE%TYPE;
  -- ... add other variables
BEGIN
  export_sales_bp(DATE '2024-07-08', v_cursor);

  LOOP
    FETCH v_cursor
      INTO v_sid, 
           v_store_code
           -- add other variables
           ;
    EXIT WHEN v_cursor%NOTFOUND;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(
      v_sid
      || ' ' v_store_code
      -- output other variables.
    );
  END LOOP;
END;
/

(Make sure you amend the PL/SQL block to add all the other variables you are selecting.)
Alternatively, from Oracle 12.1, you could use:
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE EXPORT_SALES_BP(
  FROM_DATE DATE
)
AS
  v_cursor  SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE EXP_TMP_SALES';   

  -- your insert statements ...

  OPEN v_cursor FOR
    SELECT BP_STORE_CODE,
           SALES_DATE,
           NULL AS SALE_TIME,
           RECEIPT_NO,
           UPC,
           QTY,
           GROSS_AMT,
           POS,
           NULL AS STORE_CODE_STOCK_MOV
    FROM   JAC_EXP_TMP_SALES
    ORDER BY
           BP_STORE_CODE,
           SALES_DATE,
           RECEIPT_NO;

  DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT(v_cursor);
END
EXPORT_SALES_BP;
/


Procedure creaed successfully. When exectute exec EXPORT_SALES_BP ('08-jul-2024') given me an error:  [Error] Execution (1: 7): ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'EXPORT_SALES_BP'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

@ANSAK If you are using the first version then, of course it gives an error, as it takes two arguments and you are only passing one. (Also, '08-jul-2024' is not a DATE, it is a string that happens to look like a date; DATE '2024-07-08' is a date literal or TO_DATE('08-jul-2024', 'DD-MON-YYYY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=English') would create a date from your string).

If you are using SQL Developer (or SQL*Plus) then you can use VARIABLE v_cursor REFCURSOR; EXECUTE export_sales(DATE '2024-07-08', :v_cursor); PRINT v_cursor; (and run those 3 lines as a script).

I used the first version. I run
VARIABLE v_cursor REFCURSOR;
EXECUTE EXPORT_SALES_BP(DATE '2024-07-08', :v_cursor);
PRINT v_cursor;  (and run those 3 lines as a script). but its given me an error : [Error] Execution (10: 1): ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

What IDE are you using to run the commands? (If the IDE does not support the SQL*Plus commands VARIABLE, EXECUTE and PRINT then its not surprising that they error. And the error is for line 10 - those three lines are only three lines so what command is on line 10 of your script?

sorry im not an exper in oracle. Im using toad  i just run all this three lines as a script form toad

EXECUTE JACADI_EXPORT_SALES_BP(DATE '2024-07-08', :v_cursor); Error: [Error] Execution (3: 7): ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'EXPORT_SALES_BP'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
